# Deadlock with Sequelize using beforeCreate and findOrCreate on a model

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, deadlock, sequelize.js

I'm getting the error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Here is my model:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define('User', {
        username: {type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true},
        password: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        isAdmin: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        isActive: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                User.hasMany(models.Comment);
                User.hasMany(models.Message, {as: 'receivedMessages', foreignKey: 'Receiver'});
                User.hasMany(models.Message, {as: 'sentMessages', foreignKey: 'Sender'});
            }
        }
    });

    User.hook('beforeCreate', function (user, options, fn) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function (err, salt) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                user.password = hash;
                return fn(err, user);
            });
        });
    });

    User.findOrCreate({
        where: {
            username: 'admin'
        },
        defaults: {
            username: 'admin',
            email: 'admin@admin.com',
            password: 'admin',
            isAdmin: true,
            isActive: true
        }
    });

    return User;
};
```

If I remove one of the hooks (beforeCreate or findOrCreate), it works fine.

It seems to be an issue about transaction but I can't find a way to make it work.

The doc talks about passing the transaction but I don't know how to pass the transaction to findOrCreate.
Here is the doc: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/hooks/#model-hooks

Any idea? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution but a workaround, instead of using the hook "findOrCreate", I've done it by my own:

```
User.find(
    {
        where: {
            username: 'admin'
        }
    }
).then(function (user) {
        if (!user) {
            User.create({
                username: 'admin',
                email: 'admin@admin.com',
                password: 'admin',
                isAdmin: true,
                isActive: true
            }).then(function (newUser) {
                console.log('Admin created with id: ' + newUser.id);
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Maybe not the best answer but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can also be done with Promise.resolve

```
 Promise.resolve(clientService.update(previousClient, { qa_inspection_template_id: null }, userId, transaction)).then(async ()=>
        {
            const client = await clientService.show(data.client_id, true);
            await clientService.update(client, { qa_inspection_template_id: template.id }, userId, transaction);
   
        });
```